# Error C4996 on using boost example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I have installed Boost 1.58.0 following their instructions and the examples they give in the installation guide work fine using VS2012. I also have OpenCV3.0.0 included in my properties. I want to check out an example of some graphing functions, so I copied this code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/example/astar_maze.cpp , and included stdafx.h on the top.

When compiling, I get

```
error C4996: 'std::_Fill_n': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe
```

Other people suggest either using

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
```

which doesn't seem to change anything, or turning off SDL checks via properties, which turns the error into a warning, but gives me many more errors, mostly LNK2005.

Any ideas how to get the code running?

Additional info:
Types of error when turning off SDL checks are (my project is BoostExample):

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in BoostExample.obj
error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in opencv_ts300d.lib(ts_perf.obj)
error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
```

and finally

```
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I guess this means that Boost is interacting with OpenCV and other DLLs by redefining something. Is it possible that I installed the wrong boost version? I just grabbed the main one.

Comment: The error C4996 is a compile time error. The LNK2005 is a linking error. They are reporting different issues. You need to give more information on the LNK2005 for people to help.

Comment: Thanks, added some more info on the linker errors.

Comment: The linker error tells basically the boost and the OpenCV were compiled off using different runtime settings, one for static lib and the other for DLL, and cannot be mixed used. you need to rebuild your boost and OpenCV to use same runtime setting.

Comment: That was it. I still had an older OpenCV version that seems to be compiled correctly, and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I put my comment above into answer. Please mark it as answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker error tells basically the boost and the OpenCV were compiled off using different runtime settings, one for static lib and the other for DLL, and cannot be mixed used. you need to rebuild your boost and OpenCV to use same runtime setting.